# Prove that given $a,b \in \mathbb{Z} : \gcd(a,b)=1 \Rightarrow \exists s,t : sa+tb=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

(A) let $S=\{xa+yb: x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Explain why $S$ has a smallest positive element. Denote the smallest element by $u$

Attempted Solution:
I tried plugging in values for a and b, since they can not be $0$ but the only common positive divisor is $1$. I assumed $1$ would be the only option for these values. 
I'm not sure if this is even what the question is asking.

Comment: $S\cap \Bbb N$ is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb N$, so it has a minimal element.

Comment: [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity)